# Sequelize Or condition in Join

Tags: javascript, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

I'm trying to do a query with Sequelize ORM with custom join condition.

There is the example:

```js
User.findAll({include: [{model: Post, where: {active: true}}]
```

This is the result of join condition:

```sql
INNER JOIN `posts` AS `post` ON `users`.`id` = `post`.`user_id` AND `post`.`active`=true
```

What I'm trying to do is replace the **AND** condition to **OR** and spect something like this:

```sql
INNER JOIN `posts` AS `post` ON `users`.`id` = `post`.`user_id` OR `post`.`active`=true
```

I don´t know if there is a way to do that.

Comment: Does it make sense to get ALL active posts even if they are not related to a certain user?

Comment: This is only an example and I want to replace AND to OR

Answer (score 0):

You can't add conditions to a JOIN condition with OR. You can only add additional outside conditions among which you can use OR.

```js
User.findAll({
   where: {
     [Op.or]: [
       { '$Post.somefield$': sequelize.col('some_user_field') },
       { '$Post.someotherfield$': sequelize.col('some_other_user_field') }
     ]
   },
  include: [{
    model: Post
  }
]})
```

This query will be like this in SQL:

```sql
SELECT * FROM USERS as `users`
INNER JOIN `posts` AS `post` ON `users`.`id` = `post`.`user_id`
WHERE
  `post`.`somefield`=`users`.`some_user_field`
 OR
  `post`.`someotherfield`=`users`.`some_other_user_field`
```